# How to know my server's time offset?

Tags: linux, vmware, time, synchronization, ntp

I have a few guest machines on VMware. Up until now I was keeping my time sync with ntpd inside guests. Now our VMware admins decided to setup VM hosts to keep time, so VMs don't have to. I disabled ntpd in guests, so far so good.

The problem is that I don't completely trust VMware host's timekeeping and would like to monitor time offset in guests with respect to public time sources.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ntpdate`:

```
ntpdate -d 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
```

Or for the offset only:

```
ntpdate -d 0.debian.pool.ntp.org | sed -n '$s/.*offset //p'
```